# Could not find a valid MSVC version when install YouCompleteMe

Tags: windows, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I've been trying to install YouCompleteMe to set up for my vimtex, but I encounter some problem here. I've been install python3, Cmake and Visual Studio 2019. but when I follow the instruction to compile the YCM.

```
cd YouCompleteMe
python3 install.py --all
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\ACER\vimfiles\plugged\YouCompleteMe>python3 install.py --all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\vimfiles\plugged\YouCompleteMe\third_party\ycmd\build.py", line 1326, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\vimfiles\plugged\YouCompleteMe\third_party\ycmd\build.py", line 1286, in Main
    args = ParseArguments()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ACER\vimfiles\plugged\YouCompleteMe\third_party\ycmd\build.py", line 552, in ParseArguments
    raise FileNotFoundError( "Could not find a valid MSVC version." )
FileNotFoundError: Could not find a valid MSVC version.
```

I'm using vim-plug for my plugin manager and the instruction told me to use vundle as to install it. I'm looking at some forum that YCM is so big that vim-plug will take a long time to process it, so I clone the repo and install myself and I encounter this problem. Honestly I've been new to vim so any help will be good for me. Thanks in advance :)

Based on the docs, you have to install visual studio c++ workloads for visual studio builds (I guess this is the Desktop Development with C++) and try `git submodule update --init --recursive` and still got this error, I guess this problem is related about the plugin manager that I'm using I guess?

Comment: https://github.com/ycm-core/ycmd/issues/1665

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: FWIW, YCM installs fine using vim-plug. Git is not magically faster if you run it manually. You obviously ran into the bug mentioned by phd. Use e.g. an older version.

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice, Finally can be done after installing go and change to Java 17. That's a long way to install a plugin for me, idk the alternative of YCM like deoplete seems much easier, just plug some lines into the vimrc and done. But thanks again for helping me :)